# How to fix slow website which has fatal error?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, fatal-error, uncaught-reference-error

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Yoast\WP\SEO\Helpers\Social_Profiles_Helper" not found in /home/mky89yyr/public_html/sivu/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/generated/container.php:3354**

in error lod there is multiple different fatal error with elementor, yoast seo and astra. Besides that there is also this:

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required....**

How to fix these? What the stack trace mean? Is it the instruction to fix it? I don't get it.

I have done these already in Wordpress:

- optimized photos
- installed w3 cache
- deleted unnecessary pluggins and media

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the support teams of these plugins yet? If not then give that a try, they should be able to help you figure out why their plugins are causing these PHP errors on your site.

Comment: Sounds like you simply have some files missing from your install

Comment: “Slow website” and “fatal errors” are two wildly different problems. Focus completely on the latter problem first.

Comment: To fix this specific problem, it is probably easiest to just remove and then reinstall the plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)